# How to test a Google Apps Script with multiple active users before publishing the addon?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

One of the [General requirements](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/publish) for publishing an addon for Google Docs via Google Apps Script includes this line:

> The script has been tested with multiple active users.

How does someone go about testing a script with multiple active users when the script hasn't been published and therefore can only be seen by the original author (i.e. one user)?  Assuming it is even possible to accomplish in the first place, can I complete this task by myself or do I have to have other people involved?

Comment: @pnuts - I agree.  But is there a more appropriate place on Stack Exchange to ask the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm currently testing an add on with someone else - in my case for Google Sheets. Create a goggle sheet and give them edit access. Then go to "Test as add on" and make a test using the document you created. Send them the link for the document after selecting it from the "Test as add on" modal (the URL indicates that the add on should be tested so it can't be the document's normal link).

Hope that makes sense! Seeing as this isn't pertaining to code however, I'd recommend you ask questions like these on the G+ community for Google Apps Scripts.

Comment: I don't understand the answer

Answer (score 0):

This picture could help to understand the solution:

The original doc used for testing is used to deploy the addon but on the other doc as a mirror of the original.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please try adding some explanation